# Javascript search string and display value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, for-loop

I have a react typescript project. In my `result` array I have a value that returns a url. The url contains `/Items(142)/` . I want to retrieve the item ID and store it in a variable/

I know I can do something like `result.data.odata.editLink.search()` but the number inside is always changing. How do I go about that.

Here is what I currently have.

```
for (let file of this.state.requestFiles) {
    r.item.attachmentFiles.add(file.name, file).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.data.odata.editLink);

        let requestID = //Here is where I want to put the ID fround in the url 
    })
}
```

Here is what my result console:

```
{data: {…}, file: AttachmentFile}
data:
FileName: "Capture-problem.PNG"
FileNameAsPath: {DecodedUrl: "Capture-problem.PNG"}
ServerRelativePath: {DecodedUrl: "/sites/Test/Attachments/142/Capture-problem.PNG"}
ServerRelativeUrl: "/sites/TestAttachments/142/Capture-problem.PNG"
odata.editLink: "Web/Lists(guid'24b9fe8b-3b87-44e4-b185-706d543d9567')/Items(142)/AttachmentFiles('Capture-problem.PNG')"
odata.type: "SP.Attachment"
```

The `odata.editLink` has the ID in `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always go with Regular Expressions:

```
var re = /(?:Items\()(\d+)\)/g; 
var string = "odata.editLink: \"Web/Lists(guid'24b9fe8b-3b87-44e4-b185-706d543d9567')/Items(142)/AttachmentFiles('Capture-problem.PNG')\"";
var found = re.exec(string);
var itemsVal = found[1];
console.log(itemsVal);
```

Will output `142`

Comment: This has it as a `string` however it's going to dynamically change so how would i use the `result.data.odata.editLink` instead

Comment: Just pass it the whole string :-) https://jsfiddle.net/p6vxtdhr/

Answer (score 0):

You can used a named capture group in a regular expression for this purpose:

```js
const re = /Items\((?<id>\d+)\)/
const str = "Web/Lists(guid'24b9fe8b-3b87-44e4-b185-706d543d9567')/Items(142)/AttachmentFiles('Capture-problem.PNG')"
const matches = re.exec(str)
console.log(matches.groups.id)
```

Comment: so I added your code and the `match.id` is giving me an error it's saying `Property "id" does not exist on type "RegExpExecArray"`

Comment: I'm sorry, that was me typing too fast. look at `match.groups.id` (I edited my answer to fix the issue)

Comment: Thank you. looks like I'm getting the same error. It's highlighting the `group` now. But giving the same error

Comment: That's very odd. I turned it into a runnable snippet and it's definitely working for me.

Comment: Really weird it says I  `error TS2339: Property 'groups' does not exist on type 'RegExpExecArray'`